Why is the bit-pattern 001/010/100/000/101 for 5381 significant in the magic constant in the djb2 hash function?
The reason for the number 5381 in the djb hash function was partly answered:

Magic Constant 5381: 
1. odd number
2. prime number
3. deficient number
4. 001/010/100/000/101 b


I am new to C and programming. I hope this is not too small a question as I do not have enough reputation to comment.
What does 001/010/100/000/101 b mean and what is its relevance to the question linked above?
Thank you

You say “001/010/100/000/101 is binary for 5381” and then “What does 001/010/100/000/101 b mean…?” Aside from the slashes, which appear to be for spacing, 001010100000101 is indeed the binary numeral for 5381, and appears to answer what it means. Are you asking for more information about why 5381 was used or are you asking something about the binary representation using slashes?

I edited the title to try to clarify that this question is about why 5381 having the specific binary representation 001/010/100/000/101 is being used as a justification in the linked quote

1. odd number 2. prime number 3. deficient number?  In other words, a prime number, as all primes are odd and deficient.  Could have added "natural number" and "integer" to the list...

Does the "b" mean binary...? I just noticed now. @Brian61354270 thanks

Emphasis on the "practically any good multiplier works" bit from the linked answer. djb tested this one and it was good. The binary form is maybe useful to visualize what this does, every 1 bit adds a shifted copy of the input.

@AndrewHenle: Re “all primes are odd and deficient”: Two would like a word with you.

Perhaps splitting binary numbers into groups of 3 bits (octal) was more common than splitting into groups of 4 bits (hexadecimal) in computing literature at the time it was written.

@IanAbbott Indeed, when DEC computers were common, with word sizes that were multiples of 9 and 12, octal was common. Hex took over with the ascendancy of 8, 16, and 32-bit microprocessors.

@Barmar I remember PDP-11 machine code instructions being far easier to manually decode in octal than hex!

@IanAbbott Right, it really depends on how the instructions are encoded. The PDP-8 instruction set was very octal.

@teapot418, can you give an example?

The bit pattern 001/010/100/000/101 is the binary number representation of 5381. (Often, the prefix b is used to identify the number format as binary. And you may as well omit the slashes obtianing 001010100000101b.)
The bit pattern intself does not have any relevance on the choise of the 'magic constant' 5381.
